# How do I add a EULA to a VS2008 setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, setup-project, eula

This is a very simple question with a simple answer, but it is not quite so simple to find the answer on the internet.

I have a simple Setup (deployment) project in Visual Studio 2008, and I have the EULA text.  What do I need to do in the project to get the EULA into the install wizard?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how you performed the actions in vs2003 an vs2005, I don't believe they've made changes but I'm not running vs2008 yet so I can't be certain.

right click the installation project, select View->User Interface.

In the "Start" section, right click, and select Add Dialog.  Choose the license dialog.

point the license dialog to an RTF file.